# django warning urls.W005 URL namespace isn't unique

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I am having trouble understanding the following warning. I have a namespace called "v1" and I am using these namespaces to determine versioning in my API (using django rest framework). So, I have paths like these:

```
/v1/accounts/me
/v1/listings
```

Here is the URLs configuration (project/urls.py):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='v1')),
    path('v1/listings/', include('listings.urls', namespace='v1'))
]
```

accounts/urls.py

```
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^token/$', views.obtain_auth_token, name='obtain_token'),
    url(r'^me/$', my_account, name='my_account'),
]
```

listings/urls.py

```
app_name = 'listings'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', recent_listings, name='recent_listings')
]
```

Everything works as expected. All urls are dispatched. Versioning works. However, I keep getting the following error:

> ?: (urls.W005) URL namespace 'v1' isn't unique. You may not be able to reverse all URLs in this namespace

I know it is a warning and I might be able to suppress it; however, I want to understand why this is happening. Based on my URLconf and this warning, it seems like there cannot be multiple namespaced paths as "siblings." They need to be children of one namespaced path (e.g "v1"). If my understanding is correct, how am I supposed to create this URL configuration.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically what happens is that, namespace plays a significant role on [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) finding the url. For example:

In your example `reverse('v1:obtain_token')` will return `/v1/accounts/token/`. Lets say you have two urls with same name in `accounts` and `listings`, then you might not be able to find `accounts` url in reverse query. That is why the warning is for. Better if you use different namespaces for each include. In you case, it should be:

```
path('v1/accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
path('v1/listings/', include('listings.urls', namespace='listings'))
```

Please read the [documentations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces) for more details.

#### Update

you can do the versioning like this:

```
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),  # accounts url
```

inside accounts app:

```
path('v1/token/', views.obtain_auth_token, name='obtain_token_v1'),
path('v2/token/', views.obtain_auth_token2, name='obtain_token_v2'),
...
```

Comment: Understood thanks. It doesn't make sense for me to have different namespaces because I am relying on them for versioning. Nested namespaces might work but from everything that I have looked at, I need to create a separate app for that namespace (`include` function throws error app name must be specified). Do you know if there is a way to disable this warning?

Comment: you are doing the versioning without the `namespaces`. You have defined `v1/.../` which already signifies the versioning. But maybe its more suited to do the versioning like this `/accounts/v1/token`. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am going to play with it a bit more. Writing versions per app url is an interesting idea.